# Conditional Joins in SQL

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to write a query which checks to see if a value in TblFamily is null and if it is, performs a different set of joins.  I'm getting the error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OUTER''.

I've had a look at other conditional join posts and most of them seem to be related to which field to join to, not whether or not to substitute one join for another so I haven't found any examples of correct syntax.

Any clues?

```
SELECT
  TblServiceUser.ServiceUserId

FROM
TblServiceUser

(CASE WHEN TblFamily.FamilyServiceUserId IS NULL THEN
(LEFT OUTER JOIN TblActivity ON TblActivity.ActivityServiceUserId = TblServiceUser.ServiceUserId) 
ELSE
(LEFT OUTER JOIN TblFamily ON TblFamily.FamilyServiceUserId = TblServiceUser.ServiceUserId 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TblActivity ON TblServiceUser.ServiceUserId = TblActivity.ActivityServiceUserId) 
END)
```

Comment: If you only want to show `TblServiceUser.ServiceUserId`, why join those tables at all? Or do you want to show data from those tables, too? Then please show us how the result is supposed to look like. Will you show columns that are filled from either one table or the other? Or will you show separate columns where either one set or the other is all null?

Answer (score 0):

Here what u need

```
declare @SQL varchar(max)
select @SQL = 'SELECT
  TblServiceUser.ServiceUserId
FROM
TblServiceUser'+
CASE WHEN TblFamily.FamilyServiceUserId IS NULL THEN
+'LEFT OUTER JOIN TblActivity ON TblActivity.ActivityServiceUserId = TblServiceUser.ServiceUserId+' ELSE
+'LEFT OUTER JOIN TblFamily ON TblFamily.FamilyServiceUserId = TblServiceUser.ServiceUserId 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TblActivity ON TblServiceUser.ServiceUserId = TblActivity.ActivityServiceUserId'+ END

 exec @SQL
```